# C#. Как отследить завершился ли Process?

Tags: c#

Как отследить завершился ли Process?

```
Process process = Process.Start(PATH);
```

И нужно ли что-то делать с объектом process, если процесс был завершен?

Comment: [Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) Происходит при завершении процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось использованием проверки `Process.HasExited`

Answer (score 1):

Несколько способов:

1. Пропишите что вы хотите, что бы произошло у события `Process.OnExited()`
2. После старта процесса вставьте `Process.WaitOnExit()` и программа не будет выполняться дальше, пока не завершится процесс.

Comment: В том и фишка, что мне нужно чтобы процесс (или несколько) жил сам по себе, а программа бы просто проверяла не завершился ли процесс